# Outputting Tabs with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to output lines from a .cpp file to a template in Django.  I pass the lines in a tuple called `file`, and output it one line at a time.

```
{% for line in file %}
{{line}}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Everything is very nicely autoescaped in the line, so that it is displayed correctly (like < and "), except for the \t characters.  How can I make it print these so that they show up as tabs?

I tried replacing the tabs with a few escaped space characters, `&nbsp;`, however, Django escapes the &, and it just shows up on the screen as `&nbsp;`.  I don't really want to turn of auto-escape, because it escapes everything else so nicely.

Is there an easy way for me to get these tab characters to show up correctly in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `u'\xa0'` instead.

```
u'''def foo():
\xa0\xa0return 42'''
```

Comment: Excellent!  That made the line to replace tabs: line.replace("\t", u'\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0')